Title: How to check if an image name exists in a subdirectory of Pictures after app reinstall on Android 13+?
In my app (Android 13+), I successfully create a subdirectory (e.g., "myPictures") inside the Pictures directory in shared external storage using MediaStore and scoped storage rules. Before saving an image, I check if a file with the same name (e.g., "myImage") already exists in "myPictures". If it does, I ask the user to provide a different name.
The problem arises after the user uninstalls and reinstalls the app. Images created by the previous installation of the app are now restricted by scoped storage. When I check if "myImage" exists, it returns false, even though the image still exists in "myPictures". The app ends up saving a duplicate image with a new name (e.g., "myImage(1)").
How can I reliably check if an image with a specific name already exists in a subdirectory (e.g., "myPictures") in the Pictures folder, even if the image was created by the app before it was uninstalled?
My code work fine for all previous versions
